# PHP file_get_content working on windows but not unix

Tags: php, utf-8, ascii, file-get-contents

When I'm working on local this works:

```
$file_path = utf8_decode($path); // path == folder/éèà.xml
if (file_exists($file_path)) {
            return file_get_contents($file_path);
```

The same code on my server is not working, as it can't find the file. However if I use a path as "folder/1111.xml" in the same directory it works, on local and server.

My goal is to handle properly "strange" file names and to do so I would like to encode them in ASCII, or anything that could work.

When I log the encoding mb_detect_encoding I get on Windows ASCII for $path AND $file_path, but on my server it's UTF-8, then UTF-8 again.

I tried multiple encoding "library" such as the ones from *Sebastián Grignoli* or the *Nicolas Grekas*

```
  //Sebastián Grignoli
  protected static function utf8_decode($text, $option)
  {
    if ($option == self::WITHOUT_ICONV || !function_exists('iconv')) {
       $o = utf8_decode(
         str_replace(array_keys(self::$utf8ToWin1252), array_values(self::$utf8ToWin1252), self::toUTF8($text))
       );
    } else {
       $o = iconv("UTF-8", "Windows-1252" . ($option == self::ICONV_TRANSLIT ? '//TRANSLIT' : ($option == self::ICONV_IGNORE ? '//IGNORE' : '')), $text);
    }
    return $o;
  }
```

OR

```
// Nicolas Grekas
// Generic UTF-8 to ASCII transliteration
public static function toAscii($s, $subst_chr = '?')
{
    if (preg_match("/[\x80-\xFF]/", $s)) {
        static $translitExtra = array();
        $translitExtra or $translitExtra = static::getData('translit_extra');
        $s = n::normalize($s, n::NFKC);
        $glibc = 'glibc' === ICONV_IMPL;
        preg_match_all('/./u', $s, $s);
        foreach ($s[0] as &$c) {
            if (!isset($c[1])) {
                continue;
            }
            if ($glibc) {
                $t = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $c);
            } else {
                $t = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//IGNORE//TRANSLIT', $c);
                if (!isset($t[0])) {
                    $t = '?';
                } elseif (isset($t[1])) {
                    $t = ltrim($t, '\'`"^~');
                }
            }
            if ('?' === $t) {
                if (isset($translitExtra[$c])) {
                    $t = $translitExtra[$c];
                } else {
                    $t = n::normalize($c, n::NFD);
                    if ($t[0] < "\x80") {
                        $t = $t[0];
                    } else {
                        $t = $subst_chr;
                    }
                }
            }
            $c = $t;
        }
        $s = implode('', $s[0]);
    }
    return $s;
}
```

None of those worked as mb_detect_encoding keep logging the same value and the path is still not working server side.

How can I handle any kind of path?

Comment: TL;DR: it depends on what file system you run on and how exactly it encodes file names. There's no simple portable solution to this. You should generally avoid trying to deal with non-ASCII file names. E.g. `utf8_decode` converts UTF-8 to Latin1, which happens to be the right encoding for Windows. However, Latin1 cannot represent characters like "漢字"… dealing with that *even within just Windows* is a nightmare.

Comment: In fact Latin1 is meaningless on Windows. Shared code actually appears to confuse it with Windows-1252.